# What is the @Contains equivalent in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, lotus-formula

I'm trying to see if my item.data.file (which is my file name) ends in any of the extensions, if so, then execute the line.

In lotus notes, there's @Contains so I would just do that, but does anyone know how do to this in javascript? I'm not looking for the index, or any boolean i just want to execute the line.

```
var goodExtensions = ["jpg,", "gif", "bmp", "png"];

if(image.data.file.includes(goodExtensions)
{
   //execute statement
}
```

My code is giving me errors on my if statement.

Comment: You do it it the other way round.
Extract the extension from your file, and check if `goodExtensions` includes your extension.

Comment: Since you haven't provided a specific error message, I'd take a guess and point out you're missing a closing parenthesis (`)`), which may be throwing an error. Outside of that, we can't say whether or not `includes()` is properly implemented here because we have no idea what `image` and its associated properties actually represent. You should also re-consider a design such as this one: if I'm interpreting your attempt correctly, it seems like you'll be scanning a full file name for your extensions, which would allow filenames i.e. `badFile.gif.js`.

Comment: JS has `includes`, but since you want to match extension i doubt that will be useful, you need to use regex

Comment: That worked i was missing another ')', sorry I'm using an IDE that doesn't show syntax errors.

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket in `if(image.data.file.includes(goodExtensions)`

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here would be the [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method:

```
if (goodExtensions.indexOf(extension) !== -1) {
    // the extension is on the list, do something
}
```

To find the extension from a filename, something like this should work:

```
var extension = filename.split(".").pop();
```

Comment: Why index of ? why not `includes` ? here op wants to boolean value, `includes` gives boolean where as for `indexOf` you need to change it to boolean,  OP stated this `I'm not looking for the index, or any boolean i just want to execute the line.`

Comment: Because I didn't know that method existed! And, upon examination, it looks rather new, to the extent that it isn't supported in MSIE…

Answer (score 0):

In JS, arrays have the `.include` method which checks if the array includes the argument. E.g. `[1,2,3].includes(2)`.

```js
let goodExtensions = ["jpg,", "gif", "bmp", "png"];

let isGoodFileName = fileName => {
  let extension = (fileName.match(/\.(.*)$/) || [])[1];
  return goodExtensions.includes(extension);
}

console.log(isGoodFileName('good.gif')); // true
console.log(isGoodFileName('bad.txt')); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

JS has method named [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) which is equivalent to contains, but since here you're trying to match file extension i don't think you can do it `includes` alone, you need to either split on `.` and test and last splitted element with your good extensions or use regex

In case your willing to see how to do it with regex, you can build a regex with all the good extension dynamically and test against the filename

```js
let goodExtensions = ["jpg", "gif", "bmp", "png"];
let pattern = `\\.${goodExtensions.join('|')}$`
let reg = new RegExp(pattern,'i')

let isGoodFileName = fileName => {
  return reg.test(fileName)
}

console.log(isGoodFileName('good.gif')); // true
console.log(isGoodFileName('bad.txt')); // false
```